# converting the initialization of a timer from arduino to C++

Tags: c++, timer, arduino

I am programming a code for Air Quality Sensor sen01111p.
I have the arduino code for the sensor and i am trying to convert it to a C++ code, I succeeded in most of the code till i reached these lines which i couldn't understand

```
//init the timer
TCCR2A=0;//normal model     
TCCR2B=0x07;//set clock as 1024*(1/16M)     
TIMSK2=0x01;//enable overflow interrupt     
sei();
```

So any idea can i convert them into a C++ code or how can i use a timer given that i have an imported library containing timers.

Comment: Arduino already uses C++ code! What do you mean???

Comment: Yes but i am writing a C++ program on eclipse and another board not an arduino so i cannot use the functions of the arduino

Comment: Are you using AVR microcontroller?

Comment: no a DR1174 carrier board

Comment: it would helpful if i just could translate these lines to English statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TCCR2A`, `TCCR2B` and `TIMSK2` are internal register ATmega328P microcontroller.

In particular `TCCR2A` and `TCCR2B` are registers controlling PWM, and `TIMSK2` is a register controlling Timer2. See [Secrets of Arduino PWM](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM).

If you are going to port the code on a different microcontroller you should find a way to reproduce the same PWM and timer interrupt, your mileage may vary.

Macro `sei()` enable the interrupt on microcontroller, it is a standard macro of `avr-libc` library and used in conjunction with `cli()`. See [AVR interrupts](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html#gaad5ebd34cb344c26ac87594f79b06b73).

Comment: The last thing, I found a way to write it now but i want to make sure of something. the timer used here only counts and generate an interrupt to perform a certain code in the ISR then returns to 0. right ?

Comment: yes, it enable the interrupt generation, so the corrispondig ISR will be launched.
ISR does not return, you can see them as asincronous execution.